# How to speed up scraping in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, nokogiri

This code works fine locally, but on Heroku it takes more than 30 seconds due to a request timeout:

```
if @url
  @arr = Array.new
  begin
    doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(@url))
    doc.css(".new-cars-results-box").each do |item|
      hash = Hash.new

      type = item.at_css(".new-car-name").text
      link = "http://uae.yallamotor.com"+item.at_css(".new-car-name")[:href]
      @arr << [link,type]
    end
  rescue
  end

end
```

How can I speed this up?

Comment: Your code isn't optimal, but nothing stands out that would cause it to run that much more slowly. I suggest the problem is your environment on Heroku. Please read "[mcve]" and the linked page. You're asking us to guess what you're parsing, which could directly affect the speed of processing. Using a bare `rescue` isn't good practice, but again that shouldn't affect the speed. (Output the message of the `rescue` to confirm that no exception is being ignored.)

Comment: Note also, Nokogiri will run the same speed in either location, but `open` might not. `open` isn't part of Nokogiri, it's only handing off a file-handle that Nokogiri reads to get the content of the page. If that filestream takes a while to open or is slowly feeding data it'll take a while for Nokogiri to be able to begin processing, but at no point is Nokogiri responsible for that delay.

Answer (score 0):

you query the DOM 2 times any result box when you can just query once for all the '.new-car-name', and you creating for each one useless hash

Try this:

```
if @url
    @arr = Array.new
  begin
    doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(@url))
    url_prefix = 'http://uae.yallamotor.com'
    doc.css(".new-cars-results-box > .new-car-name").each do |item|
      type = item.text
      link = url_prefix + item[:href]
      @arr << [link,type]
    end
  rescue
  end
end
```

also try to replace this line

```
doc.css(".new-cars-results-box > .new-car-name").each do |item|
```

with this:

```
doc.css(".new-car-name").each do |item|
```

Comment: While this cleans up the parsing a bit it won't affect the run-time speed of the code enough to fix a 30 second delta.